# How to clone a Windows 7 hdd into a smaller hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, clone

As above. Source is a 320gb hdd with 2 partitions (one is hidden. Laptop recovery partition). Source has no additional software issued except from whatever came from the factory. Destination is a 180gb ssd.

I'm thinking dd but unsure if can handle this of transfer. Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your're running Windows, try Macrium Reflect (no-cost version), which worked for my similar case.  It claims to get the alignment for SSDs correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but since I posted here, I'm hoping for a *nix solution. Otherwise I would've posted in superuser :)